# Изменение данных в sql через ТГ

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

Подскажите плиз. Как переписывать значения в базе. Есть бот, который заносит информацию в базу данных. Как сделать что бы в случае когда пользователь по второму разу вносит данные (в случае их измениния к примеру) в базе находился пользователь с таким id и информация менялась. Сейчас мне просто сообщается что пользователь с таким id уже существует и ничего не происходит.
Вот что из кода у меня есть в данный момент (касаемо работы с БД)

```
async def create_connection(path):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect(".\\sm_app.sqlite")
        print("Connection to SQLite DB successful")
    except Error as e:
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")

    return connection

connection = create_connection(".\\sm_app.sqlite")
conn = sqlite3.connect(r'.\\sm_app.sqlite', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()


async def db_table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_old: int, user_rest: str):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name, user_old, user_rest) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                   (user_id, user_name, user_old, user_rest))
    conn.commit()
```

пока внесение информации сильно топорное, как разберусь как переписывать строчки, буду прикручивать FSM, пока просто записываю инфу в базу

```
async def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        await message.message.answer('Привет! Ваше имя добавленно в базу данных!')

    us_id = message.from_user.id
    us_name = message.from_user.first_name
    user_old = 13
    user_rest = 'ггм'

    await bd.db_table_val(user_id=us_id, user_name=us_name, user_old=user_old, user_rest=user_rest)
```

поле юзер_ид помечено как уникальное. Я полагаю логика такая циклом пробегаемся по столбцу user_id, если находим совпадения но заполняем вносим информацию в оставшиеся 3 поля, если совпадений нет, то создаём новую запись.
пока придумал что то подобное, но не понимаю, как просмотреть весь столбец. Не могу найти

```
async def db_table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_old: int, user_rest: str):
    y: int = 0
    
    for x in ???? :
        if x == user_id:
            cursor.execute('''UPDATE user user_name = user_name, user_old = user_old, user_rest = user_rest;''')
            y = 1
            break

    if y == 0: 
         cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name, user_old, user_rest) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                   (user_id, user_name, user_old, user_rest))

    conn.commit()
```

но вот как это прописать не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Циклом проходить по БД не нужно, это будет очень не эффективно, можно просто попробовать извлечь нужное значение, раз у нас есть индекс:

```py
q = 'SELECT user FROM user WHERE user_id = ?'
my_cursor = connection.execute(q, (user_id,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row is None:
    cursor.execute('INSERT ...', ...)
else
    cursor.execute('REPLACE ...', ...)
```

А в SQLite можно поступить ещё хитрее, использовать операцию `INSERT OR REPLACE` :) Кстати, в некоторых других СУБД эта операция называется `UPSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

@AivanF
Спасибо за наводку, после долгих мытарств и экспериментов нашел таки как это сделать. Всё оказалось проще, достаточно было сделать

```
    cursor.execute('REPLACE INTO user (user_id, user_name, user_old, user_rest) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                    (user_id, user_name, user_old, user_rest))
```

Оказывается REPLASE проверят БД и при совпадении ключевого поля эту строку просто переписывает с новыми значениями, а если совпадения нет, то создаёт новую запись.
По крайней мере я так понял